# Intel Parallel Studio не хочет ставиться

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, intel

Пришлось удалить Intel Parallel Studio 2020. Затем я удалил VS 2019 и поставил VS 2022. Ставлю снова Intel PS (хоть он и не работает пока с 2022... подтормаживают они, конечно, каждый раз), он начинает удалять интеграцию с VS 2019 и выдаёт ошибку.

Как-то можно удалить эту интеграцию без 19-й студии? В удалении программ ничего не нашёл (кроме Intel C++ Redistributable, после удаления которого ничего не изменилось). Где ещё искать – непонятно.

Comment: *".. и выдаёт ошибку."* А текст ошибки по каким соображениям вы не хотите процитировать?

Comment: @Kromster, там написано см. логи. Но в них чёрт ногу сломает. В принципе, я обнаружил, что Parallel Studio теперь называется oneAPI, и там всё ок с интеграцией с VS 2022. Так что, вопрос более неактуален ;)

Comment: Какие логи и где предлагается смотреть?

Answer (score 0):

Как удалить интеграцию я не нашёл, зато обнаружен, что Parallel Studio больше не существует, теперь есть oneAPI, который интегрируется с VS 2022. Так что, вопрос более неактуален ;)